# Is there a way to make dynamic buttons on streamlit with respective IDs (or any other identifying characteristic feature)

Tags: python, sql, streamlit

I have a table where I am storing data in a Hierarchical format. My goal is to be able to view a node, and its immediate children. On clicking on one of the children, it should show the immediate children of that node.

The schema of the table is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE project (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  parent_id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES project(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Each row stores an `id`, a `name` and the `id` of its parent.

So far, I have developed code to find all children of one node, and have it reflect on the frontend.

```py
def get_children(parent_id):
    conn = connect_to_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    if parent_id == None:
        query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id IS NULL")
        cursor.execute(query)
    else:
        query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id = %s")
        cursor.execute(query, (parent_id,))

    children = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return children

def display_hierarchy(node_id):
    node = get_node(node_id)

    if node:
        st.write(f"Node ID: {node[0]}, Name: {node[1]}")

        children = get_children(node[0])

        if children:
            for child in children:
                child_button = st.button(f"Select Node ID: {child[0]}")
                if child_button:
                    display_hierarchy(child[0])

def get_node(node_id):
    conn = connect_to_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    if node_id == None:
        query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM project WHERE parent_id IS NULL")
        cursor.execute(query)
    else:
        query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM project WHERE id = %s")
        cursor.execute(query, (node_id,))

    node = cursor.fetchone()
```

I want to be able to dynamically generate buttons (on clicking a node at any level) that create more buttons (show immediate children of the clicked node). How would I go about doing that?
Additionally, is that even feasible on streamlit?